# batchapex in salesforce account field value update

Tags: batch

```
Global class praveen implements Database.Batchable<Account> {

global Database.Querylocator start(DataBase.BatchableContext Bc) {
string Query='select name,discription from account';
return Database.getQuerylocator(Query);
}

global void execute(DataBase.BatchableContext Bc,list<Account>acc) {
for(Account a:acc){
a.discription=a.Account.discription;
acc.add(a);
}
update acc;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext Bc){
}
}
```

> error: Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: Database.Querylocator at line 2 column 8

Comment: are you sure about this line `a.discription=a.Account.discription;` comment it then try. You don't need to add it again  so you can remove this line `acc.add(a);`

Comment: N.B. `global` is unnecessary unless you are building a package; `public` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes to the class:

- `Database.Batchable<Account>` changed to `Database.Batchable<sObject>`
- `select name,discription from account` changed to `select Name, Description from Account` [the field name *discription* was incorrect]
- `a.discription=a.Account.discription` changed to `a.description = a.description`

I didn't really get what you wanted to do here:

```
for(Account a : acc){
    a.description = a.description;
    acc.add(a);
}
update acc;
```

Maybe you need to review the logic according to the requirements.

Full class below:

```
global class Praveen implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global Database.Querylocator start(DataBase.BatchableContext Bc) {
        String query='select Name, Description from Account';
        return Database.getQuerylocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(DataBase.BatchableContext Bc, list<Account> acc) {
        for(Account a : acc){
            a.description = a.description;
            acc.add(a);
        }
        update acc;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext Bc){}
}
```

Comment: The `acc` list is getting the scope items duplicated in it too.

Comment: Yes, didn't really get what they wanted to do in the execute method. I only modified the code, so that it compiled successfully. Up to Praveen now, to review and modify the logic.

Comment: the specific reason for the compile error is resolved by your first bullet. I'm wondering if OP is trying to exploit the parent account relationship with the `.Account.discription` expression (wrong relationship name though)